# Rebind Click Event in AJAX after Using It Once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having trouble with a click event on an AJAX call. I have the AJAX calls nested because the click event happens on a div that doesn't exist until the first AJAX call. Basically I'm loading user comments from a database and then there is an up and down vote button on the comments. These are second ajax calls. You can see the JS here:

```
//FIRST LOAD THE COMMENTS WITH THE FIRST AJAX CALL
$('.comments_submit').each(function(){
    var comments_text = $(this).parent().find('textarea').val();
    var video_id = $(this).closest('div.home_video').find('.video').attr('id');

    var myData = 'body=' + comments_text + '&video_id=' + video_id + '&type=load';
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: 'comments_ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:myData, //post variables
                success:function(response){

                //UPON SUCCESSFULLY LOADING THE COMMENTS / BIND CLICK EVENT TO VOTE UP AND VOTE DOWN
                    $(that).closest('div.home_video').find('.comments_list').html(response);

                    $('.vote_link.down').each(function(){
                        $(this).click(function(){
                            var comment_id = $(this).closest('.comment_box').attr('id');

                            //MAKE AJAX CALL TO SUBMIT COMMENTS

                            var myData = 'comment_id=' + comment_id + '&type=vote_down';
                            var that = this;

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
                                url: 'comments_ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
                                dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                                data:myData, //post variables
                                success:function(response){

                                //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL
                                $(that).text(response);

                                },
                                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                    alert('didnt work'); //throw any errors
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });


                    $('.vote_link.up').each(function(){
                        $(this).click(function(){
                            var comment_id = $(this).closest('.comment_box').attr('id');

                            //MAKE AJAX CALL TO SUBMIT COMMENTS

                            var myData = 'comment_id=' + comment_id + '&type=vote_up';
                            var that = this;

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
                                url: 'comments_ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
                                dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                                data:myData, //post variables
                                success:function(response){

                                //REFORMAT UPON SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL
                                $(that).text(response);

                                },
                                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                    alert('didnt work'); //throw any errors
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });



                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert('didnt work'); //throw any errors
                }
        });
});
```

The server side code for the comment load is:

```
if($_POST['type']=="load"){
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE video_id = '$video_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 7";
$result_select = $mysqli->query($sql_select);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select)){
    echo "<div class='comment_box' id='".$row['id']."'>".$row['body']."
        <div class='votes'>
            <a class='vote_link up'>UP (".$row['vote_up'].")</a>
            <a class='vote_link down'>DOWN (".$row['vote_down'].")</a>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

}

And the server side code for the vote up (which is pretty much identical to the vote down code):

```
if($_POST['type']=="vote_up"){
$comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = '$comment_id'";
$result_select = $mysqli->query($sql_select);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select);
$votes = $row['vote_up'] + 1;

$sql_update = "UPDATE comments SET vote_up = '$votes' WHERE id = '$comment_id'";
$result_update = $mysqli->query($sql_update);

$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = '$comment_id'";
$result_select = $mysqli->query($sql_select);
$row_vote = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select);

echo "
UP (".$row_vote['vote_up'].")
";
```

}

A couple things. When I click the button, it will add multiple up votes to the UP or DOWN fields for some reason. But it also will unbind the click event.

I've never nested AJAX calls before so perhaps there is a better way to bind the AJAX function after the first function happens? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
$('.vote_link.down').click(function(){
    var comment_id = $(this).closest('.comment_box').attr('id');
    // etc.
});

$('.vote_link.up').click(function(){
    var comment_id = $(this).closest('.comment_box').attr('id');
    // etc.
});
```

That should simplify your code and may fix some of your issues.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. The fix was to put it in the AJAX call. I initially tried this. There's also more than one instance of each of them which is why I had to use click() inside of each().

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer (for anyone else who's having the same problem). Instead of binding the functions within the top level AJAX calls, just use $(document).on() to call the function like:

```
$(document).on("click",".vote_link.down",function(e){
     alert('testing'); 
 });
```